# Is there an API to access public Instagram content in JSON format

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to embed public Instagram images in an app based on tags.

I found the following gives the correct result :

```
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/<Tag name>/?__a=1
```

I'm unsure if this is an officially supported API.

Comment: And what does https://www.instagram.com/developer/ say about it ?

Answer (score 2):

The [Instagram API Policy](https://www.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/) applies to the usage of its official API. Instagram supports that API and notifies developers of upcoming changes. If you want to submit data to a user's Instagram account, you must use the official API.

The 'magic URL' you found is merely a JSON version of the publicly available information on that Instagram page. Indeed, you can get a JSON feed of any publicly viewable Instagram page - even the Instagram homepage itself - by appending '`?__a=1`' to it! Instagram, however, does not intend for this to be used as an official API and therefore they can make breaking changes to it at any time without notice - and have done so in the past (e.g., not so long ago the magic URL used to be '`/media`').